# Как проверить можешь ли ты писать в канал? Discord API

Tags: python, discord-api

Как проверить могу ли я отправлять сообщения в определённый канал?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.TextChannel):
if channel.permissions_for(member).send_messages:
    await ctx.send("yes")
else:
    await ctx.send("no")
```

Ввод происходит id пользователя/его упоминание и id канала или упоминание канала

[Ссылка на метод в документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.permissions_for)

Можно проверить доступ к написанием сообщений через объект [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.permissions_in)

Comment: помогло спасибо.